# Bundling in Asp.Net MVC4 and jQuery Templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, minify, bundling-and-minification

I've a question about new Bundling mechanism in Asp.Net MVC 4. Seems default Bundling supports only processing for JS\CSS. But it doesn't supports [jQuery template](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) (combining and compilation as JS code).

I found that [Cassette](http://getcassette.net) supports it in nice way - http://getcassette.net/documentation/v2/html-templates/jquery-tmpl . Cassette can compile template into javascript file to reduce client work. But I couldn't find similar functionality in buildin bundling.

I know, that there is exist IBundleTransform interface that allow to customize it. But is there are already existing BundleTransform extensions that allow to compile jQuery templates on server side?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used for my handlebar templates

Template Example: file located in ~/Templates/template123.html

```
<script id="template123" type="text/html">
    <div>someTemplate</div>
</script>
```

In the BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/templates/handlebars").IncludeDirectory("~/Templates", "*.html", true));
```

Added the following RazorExtension:

```
public static class RazorExtensions
{        
    public static IHtmlString RenderTemplates(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string src)
    {
        var context = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) || context == null || context.Request.Url == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var url = request.Url.Scheme + "://" + request.Url.Authority + Scripts.Url(src).ToHtmlString();
            var content = Client.DownloadString(url);

            return new MvcHtmlString(content);
        }

    }

}
```

On my razor page:

```
@Html.RenderTemplates("~/templates/handlebars")
```

Comment: Looks good, but it it's very similar as in the second answer. It does combining, and injecting to the page. But it doesn't convert html templates to pure javascript code as I mentioned in the question. As anyway these templates will be parsed as javascript, so that time I wanted to find way how to do it in easy way

Comment: Dude, +1 I love this answer. It's very clean I feel.

Answer (score 2):

One option is presented here:

http://samarskyy.blogspot.com/2012/03/loading-external-jquery-template-files.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. Code in that article do combining of templates or any other content. But it doesn't compile them as JavaScript as Cassette does.